# Two buttons creating unique IDs using jQuery - for jQuery UI Sortable/Draggable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, attributes, jquery-ui-sortable, unique-id

Using jQuery UI Sortable/Draggable to create submenus. I have a button at the top (`#add_submenu`) that creates a new submenu in the first dropzone (`#sortable1`). When it creates the submenu, it assigns it a new number so it has a unique ID (and I'm also using that number to give a unique number to each of the button attributes).

Inside each submenu, there's a copy button (`#copy_menu`) that clones the submenu you're clicking on, and I'm trying to change the ID (and button attributes) on the new, copied submenu to a number that's consecutive to all of the submenus that have been created.

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/abitofbrit/w8sy5u5z/

Right now, if you create a few submenus using the add submenu button, then clone some, then add more using the submenu button, you end up with a few submenus with the same ID, and obviously, that's poor syntax and it's also messing everything else up that I'm trying to do on this.

I feel like I'm overthinking this - anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of that might allow you to constantly generate a new id is to have a variable that increments up by 1 every time a new menu is created, and then have that number added to a string to make up the id. Does this help?

Comment: My friend took a look at it, and he did something similar. He set my variable as a global variable instead, and now, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fiddle with my friend's work and comments: https://jsfiddle.net/abitofbrit/L8qv5wky/

The main difference is that he replaced my variable with a global variable throughout:

```
$menuID = 0; //added global ELW
//var newMenuID = 0; //removed ELW
```

Keep in mind, there are some broken features on here at the moment because it's still being worked on, but the question I asked with changing the menu IDs is working, and that's all I need to nail down the rest of the stuff. :)